# How to return from a Cortex-M3 Hard/Usage/Bus Fault?

Tags: c, cortex-m, fault

I am working on a microkernel for cortex-m3. I have created a small test application that intentionally causes a fault.

Now I am unsure how to return from a fault. I understand that the stack likely needs to be updated with the address of a different function. I also understand that returning from faults could be a bad idea in some cases, but my kernel is written accordingly.

Here's some sample code:

```
#include "core_cm3.h"

// PSR flags

// EPSR flags
#define TFLG (1<<24)
#define puts printk
#define printf printk
#define error printk
// APSR flags
#define NFLG (1<<31)
#define ZFLG (1<<30)
#define CFLG (1<<29)
#define VFLG (1<<28)
#define QFLG (1<<27)
// IPSR flags
#define ISR_THREADMODE  0
#define ISR_NMI         2
#define ISR_HARDFAULT   3
#define ISR_MEMMANAGE   4
#define ISR_BUSFAULT    5
#define ISR_USAGEFAULT  6
#define ISR_SVCALL      11
#define ISR_PENDSV      14
#define ISR_SYSTICK     15
#define ISR_IRQ0        16

// HFSR flags
#define VECTTBL     (1<<1)
#define FORCED      (1<<30)
#define DEBUGEVT    (1<<31)

// CFSR flags

// BFSR flags
#define IBUSERR     (1<<0)
#define PRECISERR   (1<<1)
#define IMPRECISERR (1<<2)
#define UNSTKERR    (1<<3)
#define STKERR      (1<<4)
#define BFARVALID   (1<<7)

// UFSR flags
#define UNDEFINSTR  (1<<0)
#define INVSTATE    (1<<1)
#define INVPC       (1<<2)
#define NOCP        (1<<3)
#define UNALIGNED   (1<<8)
#define DIVBYZERO   (1<<9)

// MMFSR flags
#define IACCVIOL    (1<<0)
#define DACCVIOL    (1<<1)
#define MUNSTKERR   (1<<3)
#define MSTKERR     (1<<4)
#define MMARVALID   (1<<7)

// DFSR
#define EXTERNAL    (1<<4)
#define VCATCH      (1<<3)
#define DWTTRAP     (1<<2)
#define BKPT        (1<<1)
#define HALTED      (1<<0)

/** Hard Fault Handler code comes from these spots:
 *
 * http://blog.frankvh.com/2011/12/07/cortex-m3-m4-hard-fault-handler/
 * http://blog.feabhas.com/2013/02/developing-a-generic-hard-fault-handler-for-arm-cortex-m3cortex-m4/
 */

/**
 * This is the actual handler, which sets up the data to be used by the C function, then calls it.
 */
void __attribute__((naked)) HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    __asm__(
            ".thumb                                 \n"
            "   tst     lr, #4                      \n" // for priv/non-priv, test for msp or psp in return (thread or handler mode)
            "   ite     eq                          \n"
            "   mrseq   r0, MSP                     \n" // move main stack pointer into r0
            "   mrsne   r0, PSP                     \n" // move process stack pointer into r0
            "   b       hard_fault_handler          \n" // jump to the c function
            :
            :
            :
            );
}

/**
 * Here we print out the junk in the stack and some special registers to help with debugging.
 */
void hard_fault_handler(unsigned int *hardfault_args)
{
      unsigned int stacked_r0;
      unsigned int stacked_r1;
      unsigned int stacked_r2;
      unsigned int stacked_r3;
      unsigned int stacked_r12;
      unsigned int stacked_lr;
      unsigned int stacked_pc;
      unsigned int stacked_psr;
      unsigned int cfsr, bfsr, ufsr, mmfsr;
      //unsigned int control;

      stacked_r0 = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[0]);
      stacked_r1 = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[1]);
      stacked_r2 = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[2]);
      stacked_r3 = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[3]);

      stacked_r12 = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[4]);
      stacked_lr = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[5]);
      stacked_pc = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[6]);
      stacked_psr = ((unsigned long) hardfault_args[7]);
      //control = __get_CONTROL();

      // TODO 2: Eliminate printf

      puts("\n\n[Hard fault]\n");
      printf("R0 = 0x%08x\n", stacked_r0);
      printf("R1 = 0x%08x\n", stacked_r1);
      printf("R2 = 0x%08x\n", stacked_r2);
      printf("R3 = 0x%08x\n", stacked_r3);
      printf("R12 = 0x%08x\n", stacked_r12);
      printf("LR [R14] = 0x%08x  subroutine call return address.\n", stacked_lr);
      printf("PC [R15] = 0x%08x  program counter\n", stacked_pc);

      // PSR
      printf("PSR = 0x%04x ", stacked_psr);
      if (stacked_psr & NFLG) printf("N");
      if (stacked_psr & ZFLG) printf("Z");
      if (stacked_psr & CFLG) printf("C");
      if (stacked_psr & VFLG) printf("V");
      if (stacked_psr & QFLG) printf("Q");
      puts(" ");
      unsigned int isrnum = (stacked_psr & 0xff);
      switch (isrnum) {
      case ISR_THREADMODE:
          puts("Thread mode ");
          break;
      case ISR_NMI:
          puts("NMI ");
          break;
      case ISR_HARDFAULT:
          puts("HardFault ");
          break;
      case ISR_MEMMANAGE:
          puts("MemManage ");
          break;
      case ISR_BUSFAULT:
          puts("BusFault ");
          break;
      case ISR_USAGEFAULT:
          puts("UsageFault ");
          break;
      case ISR_SVCALL:
          puts("SVCall ");
          break;
      case ISR_PENDSV:
          puts("PendSV ");
          break;
      case ISR_SYSTICK:
          puts("SysTick ");
          break;
      case ISR_IRQ0:
          puts("IRQ0 ");
          break;
      }
      printf(" ");
      if (stacked_psr & TFLG)
          printf("thumb");
      else
          printf("non-thumb");
      puts("\n");

      // CONTROL (not sure this works...)
      //printf("CONTROL = 0x%04x ", control);
      //printf("\n");

      // HFSR
      printf("HFSR = 0x%08x ", SCB->HFSR);
      if (SCB->HFSR & DEBUGEVT) printf("DEBUGEVT ");
      if (SCB->HFSR & FORCED) printf("Forced Hard fault ");
      if (SCB->HFSR & VECTTBL) printf("VECTTBL ");
      puts("\n");
      // CFSR
      printf("CFSR = 0x%08x\n", SCB->CFSR);
      cfsr = SCB->CFSR;
      ufsr = (cfsr>>16);
      printf("UFSR = 0x%04x ", ufsr);
      if (ufsr & DIVBYZERO) printf("Divide by zero UsageFault ");
      if (ufsr & UNALIGNED) printf("Unaligned access UsageFault ");
      if (ufsr & NOCP) printf("No coprocessor UsageFault ");
      if (ufsr & INVPC) printf("Invalid PC load UsageFault ");
      if (ufsr & INVSTATE) printf("Invalid state UsageFault ");
      if (ufsr & UNDEFINSTR) printf("Undefined instruction UsageFault ");
      puts("\n");

      // BFSR
      bfsr = ((cfsr >> 8) & 0xff);
      printf("BFSR = 0x%02x ", bfsr);
      if ((bfsr & IBUSERR) != 0) printf("IBUSERR ");
      if ((bfsr & PRECISERR) != 0) printf("Precise Data Bus Error ");
      if ((bfsr & IMPRECISERR) != 0) printf("Imprecise Data Bus Error ");
      if (bfsr & UNSTKERR) printf("Unstacking Error ");
      if (bfsr & STKERR) printf("Stacking error ");
      if (bfsr & BFARVALID) printf("Bus Fault Address Register Valid ");
      printf("\n");
      // BFAR
      //The value of SCB->BFAR indicates the memory address that caused a Bus Fault and is valid if the bit BFARVALID in the
      //SCB->CFSR register is set.
      puts("BFAR = ");
      if (bfsr & BFARVALID) {
          printf("0x%08x\n", SCB->BFAR);
      } else {
          puts("invalid\n");
      }

      // MMFSR
      mmfsr = (cfsr & 0xff);
      printf("MMFSR = 0x%02x ", mmfsr);
      if (mmfsr & IACCVIOL) printf("Instruction Access Violation ");
      if (mmfsr & DACCVIOL) printf("Data Access Violation ");
      if (mmfsr & MUNSTKERR) printf("Memory Unstacking Error ");
      if (mmfsr & MSTKERR) printf("Memory Stacking Error ");
      if (mmfsr & MMARVALID) printf("MMARVALID ");
      puts("\n");
      // MMFAR
      // The value of SCB->MMFAR indicates the memory address that caused a Memory Management Fault and is valid if the bit
      // MMARVALID in the SCB->CFSR register is set.
      puts("MMFAR = ");
      if (mmfsr & MMARVALID) {
          printf("0x%08x ", SCB->MMFAR);
      } else {
          printf("invalid\n");
      }

      // DFSR
      printf("DFSR = 0x%08lx ", SCB->DFSR);
      if (SCB->DFSR & EXTERNAL) printf("EXTERNAL ");
      if (SCB->DFSR & VCATCH) printf("VCATCH ");
      if (SCB->DFSR & DWTTRAP) printf("DWTTRAP ");
      if (SCB->DFSR & BKPT) printf("BKPT ");
      if (SCB->DFSR & HALTED) printf("HALTED ");
      puts("\n");

      printf("AFSR = 0x%08lx\n", SCB->AFSR);
      printf("SHCSR = 0x%08lx\n", SCB->SHCSR);
      __asm volatile("BKPT #01\n"); // <-- **I want to return here**
      while (1); 
}

/*
void HardFault_Handler(void) {
    while(1);
    error("\n\n%% Hard Fault %%\n");
}
*/

void UsageFault_Handler(void) {
    error("\n\n%% Usage Fault %%\n");
}

void BusFault_Handler() {
    error("\n\n%% Bus Fault %%\n");
}

void MemMang_Handler() {
    error("\n\n%% MemMang Fault %%\n");
}
```

I have marked the line I want to return at. I currently have the Usage/Bus/Memory faults disabled but can enable them if required.

Comment: `1<<31` invokes undefined behaviour. You have the wrong type for most registers anyway. You question is too broad/opinionated. Concentrate on writing correct code. Typically if you encounter a hardfault something went blatantly wrong and there is hardly something you want to return to.

Comment: @Olaf I know, but in this case I want to return to my RTOS's `exit()` function so it terminates.

Comment: @Olaf the handler is not designed to have perfect register sizes. 1. I didn't write it. 2. it works for now

Comment: What do you mean by "recover from"? Do you mean fix the fault, fix the code, or reset the system to a mini reporter which either says "hardware fault" (if it can) or "Sorry beta version" and as much detail as possible? Consider the parallel where the system has trapped a "divide by zero" error. How can you possibly recover politely without an already in-place way of handling it, for every situation?

Comment: " the handler is not designed to have perfect register sizes ..." - with that attitude, why do you care about fault handling at all? Btw: There are definitions for all registers in the CMSIS headers. **Use them**, not some homebrew stuff. And where do you think your RTOS returns **to**?

Comment: @Olaf my RTOS returns to an `exit()` function that terminates that thread.

Comment: @WeatherVane it will exit, not continue that process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information you need is found in ARM cortex M3 technical reference manual.

You are able to query the PC that gave issued the instruction that caused the fault, the fetch address that caused the fault, the reason, etc.  You can reconstruct the exact processor state prior to the fault occurring.  This is how on-demand paging is accomplished, for example.

HOWEVER, if you're at "hard fault", there's no guarantee the rest of the system (hardware peripherals and bus infrastructure included) is capable of continuing in any meaningful way.   Your bus arbiter may be locked up; your memory controller may be fubarred, your code memory may be corrupted.   You may have experienced a brownout and some logic has gone south.   There's an endless list of things that may be wrong that you can't know and can't really recover from.

Comment: @MarkYisri  Not without simply cutting and pasting.   Search for "cortex m3 technical reference manual" and ARM has it as a PDF easily found and free of charge.